# R: mlogit returning incorrect coefficients

Tags: r, model, mlogit

Edit: The subset of the dataframe I provided way giving a different error, so I've replaced the pastebin entry with the full data frame.

Here's the top of the data frame, then read into mlogit format by `clogitdf <- mlogit.data(df1, choice= "y", shape="long", alt.var="id_var")`

http://pastebin.com/ytisEDfD

Variables:

`PriceNorm` = Price of brand normalized to size (eg. $/oz.)

`Inc` = Income

`y` = (Consumer's choice: Tide, Surf, or Wisk)

Here's the model:
`reg2 <- mlogit(y ~ PriceNorm | Inc, data=clogitdf, id.var="id_var", reflevel="surf")`

The goal is to model how consumers prefer the three brands Tide, Surf, and Wisk. When I run the model, I get a positive coefficient on `PriceNorm` and it should be negative. I'm not exactly sure what is wrong, but I feel like I might need to include the dummy variables. However, when I do, I get an error saying that the model is singular.

Can anyone help make sense of this?

Comment: I get an error from a non-invertible matrix.

Comment: @BondedDust I just tried it with the pastebin data and got the same error as you. I tried `reg2 <- mlogit(y ~ PriceNorm, data=clogitdf, id.var="id_var", reflevel="surf")` and the regression ran.

Comment: So, why do you think this is in error? Have you done any plotting?

Comment: @BondedDust I just updated the pastebin file with the full data frame and double checked to make sure it doesn't throw that error.

Comment: @BondedDust And to answer your question, a positive coefficient for Price would suggest that the consumer prefers the more expensive versions of the same product

Comment: Explain to me how a 0/1 variable represents a choice among 3 items? And while you are at it, how you are interpreting the 'tide' and 'wisk' intercepts?

Comment: @BondedDust 1 indicates the choice that was made, 0's indicate the two that weren't. The `id_var` column indicates between which three options a choice was made. The `tide` intercept indicates the additional units of utility  that a consumer gets from Tide compared to Surf. The same is true for `wisk`. The more intuitive way to think about it is in terms of willingness to pay (WTP). WTP = tide/PriceNorm and WTP=wisk/PriceNorm. And WTP says that a consumer is willing to pay (tide/PriceNorm) more $/oz. for Tide than Surf.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, now, can you explain why there are two different classes of the relationship of Price and PriceNorm?

Comment: @BondedDust Price is just a leftover in the dataframe from generating PriceNorm. PriceNorm is Price normalized to Size (ie Price/Size). Price has to be normalized to size to compare products because the product size (in ounces) varies. You can't directly compare the consumers preferance for 100 ounces of tide at $4.99 to 50 ounces of Wisk at $3.99.